# Android Tabbed Activity Searchview not opening in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview, android-search

**the problem**
I've used the `Setting Up The Search interface` doc from the official Android documentation but I'm not getting far for some strange reason as the `SearchView` refuses to open in the `Toolbar`
[cfr. Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sc)

**the code**
I've added the menu item as such:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="...">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

(Sidenote, I've also tried the v7 `SearchView` view class, but result is no different)

This is how the toolbar is laid out

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I have also added the `SEARCH` intent in the manifest and the menu gets properly inflated in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

**edit, manifest.xml and searchable.xml**
Added these by request although I don't believe they are relevant to the issue.

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="" />
```

Now according to the Android doc the `SearchView` is supposed to show up but when I press the search icon in the `Toolbar` nothing happens.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: add your manifiest file ans searchable.xml file with question

Comment: @NileshRathod I've added the manifest and searchable xml's

Answer (score 0):

Use menu item as such "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/lbl_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: As I've noted in my question I've tried nusing the v7 SearchView as well, but result is no different

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution my friend try this add your meta tag outside activity tag like this

**replace your menu with**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**now in your activity write this line of code**

```
    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pkgname">
<application
    android:name=".Utils.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
<activity
android:name=".HomeActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Tried moving the `meta-data` outside the `activity` but no luck getting it to work, the `SearchView` still won't show up

Comment: remove         app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar" from tollbar than try

Comment: @LiamMartens with my code just try thi one time     app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

Comment: Tried it but no solution still, it's got to be something else?

Comment: @LiamMartens i just copy paste your code and its workig fine in my device

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a lot I've finally found the solution.
`android:actionViewClass` should be `app:actionViewClass`.

This is never pointed out in the Android documentation.